# What should I be aiming for in terms of 'decode'/'encode' times in a remote session

Tags: remote-desktop, streaming

For various reasons I run a small windows PC purely for remote access. [Parsec](https://parsec.app) is my 'favoured' remote access tool, and I might be experimenting with running games remotely on a more powerful box than the little ryzen laptop grade system I have now.

One of the things with parsec is its trivial to get information on latency and how long processes are taking

[image]

With minor experiments - while network latency and bitrate aren't stuff I can 'directly' adjust - I'm alright with 720 or 1080p remotely

If I'm planning to try to game on this, what sort of latencies should I be looking at as a target in general? I might get better performance than this dinky little box on a 'proper; gaming rig, so I'd not take the fairly long encode times on this as a benchmark

I may look at other options (Steam seems good for in home streaming for example) - so I'm looking at ways to more 'generally' look at appropriate latency

Answer (score 0):

> *"If I'm planning to try to game on this, **what sort of latencies should I be looking at as a target in general?**"*

This question can't be an answered without an understanding of,

- the type of game
- the level of competition

Obviously if you're playing an untimed turn-based game latency will not be an issue. If you're playing a FPS at a competitive/professional level latency will be an issue. And everything else is on a spectrum between them.